# SwiftLint: Is it possible to disable rules for a specific parameter?

Tags: swift, swiftlint

I have a logging method that will inevitably be called with a parameter that violates the hardcoded_string rule of SwiftLint:

```
Logger.log("This will be a hardcoded string usually")
```

I am aware that I can use swiftlint:disable:next each time, but is it possible to specify in the Logger class definition that swiftlint should just always ignore this particular parameter? Something like:

```
/// Implementation of Logger

/// Logs a message
/// - Parameter messsage: The message to log swiftlint:disable hardcoded_string
func log(_ message: String) { ... }
```

Comment: Disabling `hardcoded_string` all together in your swiftlint.yml?

Comment: Nope, I don't want to disable it globally. I want to disable it in this specific case.

Comment: How about writing custom rule which disables hard coded string except Logger.log() calls?

Answer (score -1):

You can write this line

```
// swiftlint:disable force_cast
```